# Trouble implementing a recursive Add method for a Linked-List class

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, linked-list

I am required to implement the `add` method for a linked list class recursively. I cannot get my code to work. This is what I have so far:

```py
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def add(self, val, current_node=0):

        if current_node == 0:
            current_node = self.head

        if current_node is None:
            current_node = Node(val)
        else:
            self.add(self, val, current_node.next)
```

Where have I gone wrong with this implementation?

Answer (score 1):

This is a misuse of recursion. If the length of the linked list is more than the call stack size, the class breaks for no reason. It's also less efficient and less intuitive to write than an iterative implementation.

Having said that, it's common for professors to require algorithms that aren't naturally suited for recursion to be implemented recursively. Playing along, I'd write an inner helper that handles the actual recursion. This avoids the awkward default parameter that can confuse the caller and can enable them to break the function's contract.

```
def add(self, val):
    def add_recursively(curr, prev):
        if curr:
            add_recursively(curr.next, curr)
        else:
            if prev:
                prev.next = Node(val)
            else:
                self.head = Node(val)

    add_recursively(self.head, None)
```

The main issue with the original attempt is this:

```
if current_node is None:
    current_node = Node(val)
```

Without a reference to the previous node in the chain, `current_node` isn't actually attached to anything using the above operation, so it just gets garbage collected when the function returns.

If you're allowed to use iteration, this is a more natural approach:

```
def add(self, val):
    curr = self.head
    prev = None

    while curr:
        prev, curr = curr, curr.next

    if prev:
        prev.next = Node(val)
    else:
        self.head = Node(val)
```

Here's a minimal, complete usage example:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, next_node=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next_node

    def __str__(self): 
        return str(self.val)

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def add(self, val):
        curr = self.head
        prev = None

        while curr:
            prev, curr = curr, curr.next

        if prev:
            prev.next = Node(val)
        else:
            self.head = Node(val)

    def __str__(self): 
        nodes = []
        curr = self.head

        while curr:
            nodes.append(curr.val)
            curr = curr.next

        return "[" + " -> ".join(nodes) + "]"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    llist = LinkedList()
    llist.add("bananas")
    llist.add("apples")
    llist.add("cranberries")
    print(llist) # => [bananas -> apples -> cranberries]
```

Beyond this, consider keeping a `self.tail` node reference for your `LinkedList` class. This would make add operations O(1) instead of O(n).

Comment: Thank you very much for the throughout explanation. I tried testing your version of the code and it works for the most part. However, when I try to print the data of a newly added node in a previously empty linked-list, it prints the node object id instead of the value.

For example, the following prints a node object's ID instead of the node object's value:  
   linkedlist1 = LinkedList(), 
   print(linkedlist1.head.data)

Comment: The small code snippet you provided here shouldn't work since `head` is initially `None` but I had no problem printing the data in my test code. I added a usage example--let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: I made a mistake with my sample test code and got yours to work. I also created all the other linked list methods based on the add method you provided, thank you very much for showing me the way! Sorry for the late response!